# Screen glitching on laptop monitor in UBUNTU 22.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 22.04, display, display-resolution

My problem involves strange screen glitches on my laptop's display. These glitches are quite disruptive as they hinder my work and computer usage. Interestingly, the situation is completely different when my laptop is connected to an external monitor. In that scenario, everything works smoothly, and there are no glitch-related problems on the external monitor.

Initially, I tried different cables, including HDMI, USB-C, and eventually settled on DisplayPort. It seemed like the issue disappeared, but when I attempted to connect to a monitor again, the glitches resurfaced.

I also attempted to adjust the screen's refresh rate. At one point, I changed the default 144 Hz refresh rate to 77 Hz (using the xrandr tool). It seemed like the glitch issue on the laptop screen was resolved, and the display worked smoothly even without the external monitor connected.

Unfortunately, when I connected to the monitor again, the problems returned. I have a suspicion that the refresh rate adjustment might have had an impact on this situation. I suppose that what initially appeared to be a solution might have contributed to these issues.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Is there a proper way to adjust the screen's refresh rate on a laptop running Ubuntu to avoid glitches on the screen? Could my assumption about the refresh rate be valid? I'd appreciate any advice or pointers that could help me understand and resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

6.2.0-26-generic
OS: LINUX-X86_64
NVIDIA DRIVER: 535.86.05
NVML VER: 12.535.86.05
I don't have the option to change from 144Hz to 60Hz in the Ubuntu settings.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Release: 22.04 Codename: jammy

https://streamable.com/r5d4gn: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwqCE.png